# how to get value from listview.setadapter(adapter)?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-listview

Good evening everyone.

first of all, I have two activities that uses the same piece of code. In 1 activity this code works great. I get the value in the listview. Btw, this activity uses a listview making reference to a RecipesDataSourceAdapter, RecipesDataSource, and RecipesDataSourceContent (this is not a SQLite database referrence). In the second activity, that gives me an error when I click on the listview to get the value. Btw, this activity uses a sqlite database as reference.

Furthermore, I have try using just: extends ListActivity, extends Activity implements onClickListener, and extends ListActivity implements onClickListener and in all I get the same error.

here is the code:

```
private YAODeckListDataSource datasource;

private ListView recipesListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.frmdeckedithome);

   copydbfromassest();



    datasource = new YAODeckListDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();


      List<YAODeckList> values = datasource.getAllComments();  

      ArrayAdapter<YAODeckList> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<YAODeckList>(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);


      recipesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstcard);  

      recipesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recipesListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        recipesListView.setClickable(true);
        recipesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
            {


                // ListView Clicked item index (the position)
                 int itemPosition     = position;

                 // ListView Clicked item text (the text displayed)

                 TextView name;
                 name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.list.text);
                 String message = name.getText().toString();  /// <<<<<< here is where i get an error
                 //displaying the information in popmessage
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(YAOhomedeckedit.this);
                    adb.setTitle("ListView OnClick");
                    adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = "+ (position + 1)+ " of " + recipesListView.getCount() +"  "+ 
                            "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem Text : " + message );

                    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                    adb.show();

            }
        });
}
```

The good thing is that the listview gets populated with the corresponding information but when I click on the list item i get error.

```
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500): java.lang.NullPointerException
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at com.example.yao.YAOhomedeckedit$1.onItemClick(YAOhomedeckedit.java:129)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
      07-09 06:23:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I Guess the name object is null better check that id once so it may solves your problem.

Comment: YAOhomedeckedit.java line 129, error: NullPointerException, fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yout `name textview` is **null** because it is not part of `View v`.And you may direcltly cast `View v` to `Textview` as `((TextView) v).getText()` because you don't need to create view again.

i.e. In your code,get message as

```
String message =  ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
```

instead of

```
TextView name;
name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.list.text);
String message = name.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because of the following line

```
name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.list.text);
```

You are passing the layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in `adapter` and it does not have the `TextView` with id `text` which you are trying to do in above line

Check out the source code for [android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml)

So you can either use

```
name = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

or

```
name = ((TextView) v);
```

as the layout only contains a single `TextView`

Comment: Thank you, You guys have been a great help

Answer (score 0):

```
public View findViewById (int id)
// Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).
// Returns The view if found or null otherwise.
```

In your code,

```
name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.list.text);
```

The above line is wrong. You must send the id attribute of the view you want to access.